# PHP 5.5 not finding MySQLi constructor

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, mysqli, amazon-ec2

I have mySQL and PHP 5.5 installed on an AWS EC2 instance.  However, when I try

```
$db = new mysqli($args)
```

PHP kicks me to the autoloader, as if it can not find the constructor for the mysqli object.  I have uncommented extension=mysql.so in the php.ini file, but that does not seem to have accomplished anything.  At startup, I get

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/msql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I thought that mysqli/native driver came prepackaged with PHP5.5, but maybe I was wrong about that. Can someone give me a hint as to how PHP5.5 plays with mysqli?

Comment: but the required extension should be mysqli

Comment: I tried both.  Mysql.so was the default commented, so I went with that once Mysqli.so didn't work.

Comment: Do I need to change both php.ini and php-5.5.ini?

Comment: Yep, same error.     PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/msqli.so' - /usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/msqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't come prepackaged in the case of Amazon Linux. It's an addon module (Assuming you are using Amazon Linux). You can run:

```
sudo yum install php55-mysqlnd
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to `sudo service httpd restart`. Didn't know I had to do that and it had me messed up for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe misspelled? PHP is trying to load msqli.so, not mysqli.so. Check that you write "extension=mysqli.so", not "extension=msqli.so"